# Keras Network with 2d Array

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I have the following input array, which I want to feed to a CNN

```
import numpy as np 
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D
#dummy data for 1d array
width = 5
levels = 4
inputArray =np.random.randint(low=0, high=levels, size=20)
inputArray_ = inputArray.reshape(-1,width) #reshape to 2d array
```

the first layer of the network is:

```
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputArray_)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Layer conv2d_13 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.   Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input: [array([[3, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 3, 1, 3],
   [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
   [1, 3, 2, 2, 0],
   [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
   [0, 3, 1, 3, 0],
   [3, 1, 2, 3, 2],
   [1, 2, 0, 2, 2],
   [3, 2, 2, 1, 0],
   [1, 2, 1, 3, 1],
   [0, 3, 2, 3, 0],
   [0, 3, 1, 0, 0],
   [2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
   [2, 2, 1, 0, 1],
   [3, 3, 0, 3, 1],
   [0, 0, 3, 1, 0],
   [1, 3, 1, 2, 2],
   [1, 0, 3, 2, 2],
   [3, 1, 2, 1, 2],
   [3, 0, 3, 3, 1]])]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your array to a tensor.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
#dummy data for 1d array
width = 5
levels = 4
inputArray =np.random.randint(low=0, high=levels, size=20)
inputArray_ = inputArray.reshape(-1,width)
print(type(inputArray_))



inputTensor_ = K.constant(inputArray_)

print(type(inputTensor_))
print(inputTensor_)
```

[image]

Comment: This returns the following error

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_15: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `Input` layer instead of `inputArray_` to `Conv2D` layer. While defining a neural network's architechture, we only pass the placeholders and not the actual values.

```
inputArray =np.random.randint(low=0, high=levels, size=20)
inputArray_ = inputArray.reshape(-1,width, 1) #Conv2D accepts 3D array

input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=(None, width, 1), dtype='float32')
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_data)
```

Comment: Using the following layout:
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_data) 
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
encoder = Model(inputArray_, encoded)

inputArray_ gives the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: It's a different error now. You are passing incorrect inputs to the Model. I would suggest you to check examples on keras documentation, they are super easy to follow: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/